# jQuery Horizontal Scrolling (Sliding divs on click)

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

Im looking to slide the green div off screen and slide the red one into view when you click the login link.
For some reason I cant get it to work. My jquery skills are quite bad so any help would be amazing.

Heres a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ibucus/pL758ota/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#loginlink').click(function(){

    $('div#frontpageanimateblock').animate({'left':'-=700px'});

});

$('#loginlinkback').click(function(){

    $('div#frontpageanimateblock').animate({'left':'+=700px'});

});

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use margin-left instead

```
'marginLeft': '-=640px'
```

take a look on fiddle

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/pL758ota/3/)